# Nonlinear Regression & Optimisation

Tags: matlab, parameters, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I need some help... I have got a model function which is :

```
function y = Surf(param,x);

global af1 af2 tData % A2 mER2 
A1 = param(1); m1 = param(2); A2 = param(3); m2 = param(4); 
m = param(5); n = param(6); 

k1 = @(T) A1*exp(mER1/T);
k2 = @(T) A2*exp(mER2/T);
af = @(T) sech(af1*T+af2);

y = zeros(length(x),1);
for i = 1:length(x)
    a = x(i,1); T = temperature(i,1);
    y(i) = (k2(T)+k1(T)*(a.^m))*((af(T)-a).^n);
end 

end
```

And I have got a set of Data giving Cure, Cure_rate, Temperature. Which are all in a single vertical column matrix.

Basically, I tried to use :

```
[output,R1] = lsqcurvefit(@Surf, initial_guess, Cure, Cure_rate)
[output2,R2] = nlinfit(Cure,Cure_rate,@Surf,initial_guess)
```

And they works pretty well, (my initial_guess are initial guess of parameters in the above model which is in : [1.1e+07 -7.8e+03 1.2e+06 -7.1e+03 2.2 0.72])

My main problem is, when I try to look into different methods which could do nonlinear regression such as fminsearch, fmincon, fsolve, fminunc, etc. They just dont work and I am quite confused about the input that I am considering. Mainly beacuse they dont work as same as nlinfit and lsqcurvefit (input of Cure, Cure_rate), most of them considered the model function and the initial guess only, The way I did the above:

```
output3 = fminsearch(@Surf,initial_guess)
output4 = fsolve(@Surf,initial_guess)
output5 = fmincon(@Surf,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq) 
(Not sure what should I put for Linear Inequality Constraint:
 A,b and Aeq,beq )
output6 = fminunc(@Surf,initial_guess)
```

The problem is Matlab keep saying either I have not enough input or too many input which I don't get it and how should I include my Dataset in the fitting function (Cure, Cure_rate) in the above functions, like in nlinfit and lsqcurvefit?

Comment: Just a clarification, `lsqcurvefit` is not a mathematical method (nor are the others), as I mentioned in your other posts. Its a MATLAB function. For example, on of the possible methods that `lsqcurvefit` may use, if the code inside decides that its a good idea, is the Interior Point Method. This is a method. I don't know all MATLAB functions and what they do inside, but the fact that you are using a different function **does not mean** that you are using a different method, and you can also use different methods within the same function .

Comment: I have tried 

x = fminunc(@Surf, initial_guess)

but it said 

Not enough input arguments.

Error in Surf (line 11)
y = zeros(length(x),1);

Error in fminunc (line 278)
        f = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINUNC cannot continue.

Comment: OK.... but that has nothing to do with what I said. I suggest reading the documentation for the problems you are finding